# pgfplots legend style for plots with error bands

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make a plot with several data rows and error bands like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
0 128 1.13137 128.058 2.26326 117.25 10.8282
0.261799 127.046 1.12715 130.626 2.28583 132.992 11.5322
0.523599 124.249 1.11467 126.131 2.24616 133.772 11.566
0.785398 119.799 1.09453 121.163 2.20148 124.264 11.1474
1.0472 114 1.06771 112.967 2.12572 113.615 10.6591
1.309 107.247 1.0356 105.166 2.05101 112.295 10.597
1.5708 100 1 98.8555 1.98852 82.6604 9.09178
1.8326 92.7531 0.963084 90.31 1.90063 86.6324 9.30765
2.0944 86 0.927362 88.2214 1.87853 99.0388 9.95182
2.35619 80.201 0.89555 79.8697 1.7874 85.4422 9.24349
2.61799 75.7513 0.870352 75.4327 1.73704 83.2534 9.12433
2.87979 72.9541 0.854132 72.8971 1.7076 63.5106 7.96935
3.14159 72 0.848528 73.2027 1.71117 69.531 8.33853
}\datatable

\tikzset{
    error band/.style={fill=orange},
    error band style/.style={
        error band/.append style=#1
    },
}
\pgfplotsset{
  tick label style={scale=0.3},
  line and fill/.style={legend image code/.code={%
      \fill[##1,draw=none] (0mm,-1ex)--(0mm,1ex)--(6mm,1ex) -- (6mm,-1ex) \closedcycle;
      \draw[##1] (0mm,0mm)--(6mm,0mm);
    }
  }
}
\newcommand{\errorband}[6][]{
    \addplot [draw=none, stack plots=y, forget plot] table [
        x={#3},
        y expr=\thisrow{#4}-\thisrow{#5}
    ] {#2};
    \addplot [fill=gray!40, stack plots=y, area legend, opacity=0.5, #1, draw=none] table [
        x={#3},
        y expr=2*\thisrow{#5}
    ] {#2} \closedcycle;
    \addlegendimage{line and fill,#1}
    \addlegendentry{#6}
    \addplot [forget plot, stack plots=y,draw=none] table [x={#3}, y expr=-(\thisrow{#4}+\thisrow{#5})] {#2};
    \addplot [thick] table [
      x={#3},
      y expr=\thisrow{#4},
    ] {#2};
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    width=.5\textwidth,
        ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel=Observable,
    ylabel=Events,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    ymin=50,ymax=150,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend image post style={scale=.3},
    legend style={draw=none,fill=none,align=left,nodes={scale=0.3, transform shape}}, 
]
  \errorband[draw=black,fill=green!50!black ]{\datatable}{0}{5}{6}{Morphing output (Input Set B)}
  \errorband[draw=black,fill=black!50!white ]{\datatable}{0}{3}{4}{Morphing output (Input Set A)}
  \errorband[draw=black,fill=violet!50!white]{\datatable}{0}{1}{2}{True Template}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the legend entries are completely messed up. I'd like to have the legend pictures show a filled area with the fill color used for the band, and through that a single line with the line style used for the mean values, but I don't really understand what is going on here or why it looks so messed up...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost did it right. Three little changes and I think that is the desired result, right?

1. Replace `\closedcycle` by `-- cycle` in the `legend image code`,
2. add `forget plot` to each `\addplot` in `\errorband`, and
3. move `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry` after the last `\addplot` in `errorband`.

I think that where all major changes I have done. If I have missed something, you will see it in the following code, where I also commented some stuff that is not needed in this example.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
        0 128 1.13137 128.058 2.26326 117.25 10.8282
        0.261799 127.046 1.12715 130.626 2.28583 132.992 11.5322
        0.523599 124.249 1.11467 126.131 2.24616 133.772 11.566
        0.785398 119.799 1.09453 121.163 2.20148 124.264 11.1474
        1.0472 114 1.06771 112.967 2.12572 113.615 10.6591
        1.309 107.247 1.0356 105.166 2.05101 112.295 10.597
        1.5708 100 1 98.8555 1.98852 82.6604 9.09178
        1.8326 92.7531 0.963084 90.31 1.90063 86.6324 9.30765
        2.0944 86 0.927362 88.2214 1.87853 99.0388 9.95182
        2.35619 80.201 0.89555 79.8697 1.7874 85.4422 9.24349
        2.61799 75.7513 0.870352 75.4327 1.73704 83.2534 9.12433
        2.87979 72.9541 0.854132 72.8971 1.7076 63.5106 7.96935
        3.14159 72 0.848528 73.2027 1.71117 69.531 8.33853
    }\datatable
%    \tikzset{                          % <-- not needed here
%        error band/.style={fill=orange},
%        error band style/.style={
%            error band/.append style=#1
%        },
%    }
    \pgfplotsset{
%        tick label style={scale=0.3},  % <-- not needed
        line and fill/.style={
            legend image code/.code={%
                % you have to use `-- cycle' instead of `\closedcycle'
                % (`\closedcycle' appends the path after the last coordinate
                %      `-- (x of last coordinate,0)
                %       -- (xmin,0)
                %       -- (xmin,y of first coordinate)'
                %  which isn't what you wanted.)
                \fill [
                    ##1,
                    % added opacity so the look in the legend is the same
                    % as in the plot
                    opacity=0.5,
                    draw=none,
                ] (0mm,-1ex) -- (0mm,1ex) -- (6mm,1ex) -- (6mm,-1ex) -- cycle;
                \draw [##1,fill=none] (0mm,0mm) -- (6mm,0mm);
            },
        },
    }
    \newcommand{\errorband}[6][]{
        % here all the plots need to be "forgotten" ...
        \addplot [
            draw=none,
            stack plots=y,
            forget plot,
        ] table [x={#3},y expr=\thisrow{#4}-\thisrow{#5}] {#2};
        \addplot [
            fill=gray!40,
            stack plots=y,
%            area legend,               % <-- not needed
            opacity=0.5,
            #1,
            draw=none,
            forget plot,
        ] table [x={#3},y expr=2*\thisrow{#5}] {#2} \closedcycle;
        \addplot [
            stack plots=y,
            draw=none,
            forget plot,
        ] table [x={#3},y expr=-(\thisrow{#4}+\thisrow{#5})] {#2};
        \addplot [
            forget plot,
            thick,
            #1,
            fill=none,
        ] table [x={#3},y expr=\thisrow{#4}] {#2};
        % ... and the legend image and entry have to be given at the end
        \addlegendimage{line and fill,#1}
        \addlegendentry{#6}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%            no markers,                % <-- not needed
            width=.5\textwidth,
            ylabel near ticks,
            xlabel near ticks,
            enlarge x limits=false,
            xlabel=Observable,
            ylabel=Events,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin=50,
            ymax=150,
            legend cell align=left,
            % (changed (both) scalings from 0.3 to 0.5 so they can be
            % better seen in the screenshot)
            legend image post style={scale=0.5},
            legend style={
                draw=none,
                fill=none,
%                align=left,            % <-- not needed
                nodes={
                    scale=0.5,
%                    transform shape,   % <-- not needed
                },
            },
        ]
            \errorband [%
                draw=black,
                fill=green!50!black,
            ]{\datatable}{0}{5}{6}{Morphing output (Input Set B)}
            \errorband [%
                draw=black,
                fill=black!50!white,
            ]{\datatable}{0}{3}{4}{Morphing output (Input Set A)}
            \errorband [%
                draw=black,
                fill=violet!50!white,
            ] {\datatable}{0}{1}{2}{True Template}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]